# How to add React component to html after getElementById

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to render a react component run time if `innerText` contain '*Response*' how we can append react component in html after getting div `getElementById`

ie:

```
str = 'my name is _Response_ and I am from _Response_'

var comp = str.replace(/_Response_/g,<TextField />)
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the string into an array containing `_Response_` and non-`_Response_` substrings, then replace the `_Response_` ones with the React component.

For example, to make a runnable snippet, using `<input>`s instead of `<TextField>`s:

```js
const str = 'my name is _Response_ and I am from _Response_'

const App = () => {
    return str
      .split(/(_Response_)/)
      .map(substr => substr === '_Response_' ? <input /> : substr);
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('.react')).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```